# Hide table rows except head

Tags: javascript, html

Without Jquery or any JavaScript library i need to hide the rows of a simple html table except for the table head on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
.mytable tr {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Just kidding. Here we go:

```
<table border="1" id="mytable">
<th>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
</th>
<tr>
    <td>asdkjas</td>
    <td>asdasdjwa</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>asdkjas</td>
    <td>asdasdjwa</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    hideTableRows();
}
function hideTableRows() {
    var myTableRows = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(i=0;i< myTableRows.length;i++) {
        myTableRows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I think a table requires rows, won't display with just headers.. I could suggest adding a blank row at the start of the table, and changing "i" in the for loop to 1. That way the first row should be skipped.

HTH
Marko

Answer (score 5):

if your table is correctly marked up.
You can do something like :

```
document.getElementById('yourtable')
        .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
        .style.display = 'none';
```

Then put this on an 'onload' event

You could also do it in CSS + Javascript by setting a global .js class to your  tag and then use CSS selector.

```
html.js #yourtable tbody 
{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: OP says "Without Jquery or any JavaScript library", he wants a solution with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No particular need to resort to javascript, you can do the trick through CSS too:

```
#table_id tr
{
  display:none;
}
```

This should hide all `TRs` not `TH`.

Comment: From an accessibility point of view, you should not hide data which are likely to be never showed without the use of javascript.